# swift _ Pushing ViewController in gives a black screen

Tags: swift, ios13.3

[image]

I have two screens the first one"ViewController" has tableview  and the second  "MapViewController" one contains MKMapView   when i navigate from the first one to the second    the second one looks like  black screen  the second screen is supposed to appear the apple map    can any one help me ?

```
 import UIKit
import  MapKit
struct Category {
    let place : String
    let coordinates  : [Double]
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let tableview : UITableView={
        let table = UITableView()
        table.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        return table
        
    }()
    private let data : [Category]=[
    Category(place: "Misr bank ", coordinates: [30.576352,31.503955])

    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(tableview)
        tableview.delegate=self
        tableview.dataSource=self
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        tableview.frame=view.bounds
    }


}

extension ViewController:UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let category = data[indexPath.row]
        let mapview = MapViewController(coor: category.coordinates)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mapview, animated: true)
    }
}
```

MapViewController

```
    import UIKit
import MapKit
class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
    private let coor : [Double]
    
    init(coor:[Double]){
        self.coor=coor
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        
        let lat = coor[0]
        let long = coor[1]
        print(lat)
        print(long)

    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
```

Comment: Just so you understand why I voted to close - it's virtually impossible to help you without more details. Off the top of my head? Are you using IB and the IBOutlets aren't set up properly? How are you navigating? Do you have some kind of typo? Please note that I didn't downvote. But how can you expect anyone to help you if you do not give us enough details to know what issue you have? Maybe if someone can duplicate things they could help.

Comment: Please upload some code and more details. Possibly a screenshot of your storyboard, if you are using one

Comment: sorry everyone  i added two images for ViewController and MapViewController

Comment: Do not show pictures of code. Show _code_.

Comment: okay i added my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like MapViewController is designed in the storyboard. (If it were not, you would not be talking about `@IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!`)

But if so, then saying `MapViewController(coor: category.coordinates)` is not how to retrieve the instance that you designed in the storyboard. If you say that, you will indeed get basically an empty interface.

Instead, give that instance in the storyboard an identifier, and in your code, ask the storyboard to instantiate the view controller that has that identifier.

You will also have to rearrange your initialization completely. The storyboard is going to call `init(coder:)`, not `init(coor:)`. In fact, you can get rid of the latter entirely:

```
@IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
var coor = [Double]()
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder:coder)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let lat = coor[0]
    let long = coor[1]
    print(lat)
    print(long)
}
```

Now when you instantiate MapViewController from the storyboard, immediately also set `mapView.coor` before pushing.

Comment: And see my http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake-2/

Comment: i instanced in the storyboard an identifier and asked the storyboard to instantiate the view controller that has that identifier i added this code   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let mapCV = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Map")  as! MapViewController
          present(mapCV, animated: true, completion: nil)   . but  an error appearing "init(coder:) has not been implemented"

Comment: Yes, I can see why. You need to implement it.

Comment: can you help me more how to implement it ?

Comment: Added some more info, hope it helps.

Comment: thank you  the problem is solved like you said